# Android Deploy kotlin sources to a maven repository

Tags: android, maven, gradle, kotlin, nexus

What is the gradle configuration to ensure kotlin sources are included in the sources classifier jar to be deployed in a maven repository ?

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume you are using a custom maven deploy gradle configuration let's say the one provided by Chris Banes https://github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push

The only thing you need to do is to specify you are using *.kt files (assuming you are mixing java & kotlin files in the java folder)

```
    android {

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                include '**/*.java'
                include '**/*.kt'
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Edit:
Ofc this only adds the code in the sources.jar. Now IntelliJ needs to use it...

Comment: +1 thanks that did the trick for me. Both KDoc and Kotlin source code are now included when shipping mixed-language (Java/Kotlin) libraries to Maven.

Answer (score 0):

As a variation of method:

```
sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/main/myKotlin'
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/myJava'
}
```

Of course, this is for Kotlin DSL gradle, not Groovy DSL gradle:)